# In Solr, what is the maximum size of a "text" field?

Tags: solr

When using Solr client in your app, what is the max size of a `text` multi line field?

Can I send huge xml documents as text?

E.g.

```
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
document.addField("id", rec.getId());
document.addField("hugeTextFile_txt", hugeTextFile);        
UpdateResponse response = solr.add(document);
solr.commit();
```

Comment: What drives your need to send huge XML documents to Solr?  Will they be indexed for searchability, or just stored and returned with results?

Comment: There is update in the answer, which I posted earlier. Please check.

Comment: Which version are you using? Between Solr 3 and 4 there has been a change to this.

Comment: 4 latest from solr website at the time this ticket was created.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update**

I used the same unit test using `text` fieldType. Below is the declaration I used. Please note that I have removed analyzer section from declaration.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"/>
```

I was able to add **500,000,000** characters and index it successfully. For higher value I got `Java heap space` error, which is not related to the solr.

---

I tried to perform a simple test by adding a large value to a field. The limit I found is **32,766 bytes**. After that It throws `IllegalArgumentException`. The `fieldType` for `email` was `string`.

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
```

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
  SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
  document.addField("profileId", TestConstants.PROFILE_ID);
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i<32767; i++) {
    builder.append((char)((i%26)+'a'));
  }
  document.addField("email", builder.toString());
  solrClient.add(document);
  solrClient.commit();
}
```

Exception thrown by above for 32767 and more:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="email" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 97, 98, 99, 100]...', original message: **bytes can be at most 32766 in length**; got 32767

I hope this would help.

Comment: .. but a `string` field is not the same as a `text` field. If anything you've probably found the limit of a single token.

Comment: @MatsLindh You were right. I have added my finding for `text`, please check. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Great thanks for this answer. as advertised, i'm running just fine putting pretty darn big text files inside txt dynamic solr fields.

Comment: That is almost exactly 32KiB, minus to bytes to represent the BOM of UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

changing the solr field to "text_general" and updating the solr schema helped

commands to update solr schema:

solrctl instancedir --update "directory that contains the schema file with the edited solr field"

solrctl collection --update "collection-name to update"