# Solr field memory requirements

Tags: solr, byte

How would one go about finding the memory requirements associated with a specific solr field type?

Example: I'm trying to find how many bytes are allocated per string on a SOLR entry, but I am having a hard time trying to calculate it on my own. I have also searched for documentation and come up empty handed

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936361/in-solr-what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-text-field ?

Comment: @Oyeme Thanks for sharing I hadn't seen that. While informative, it still doesn't answer my initial question. What it does tell is the upper limit of a SOLR token. I don't intend on getting anywhere near the upper limit, (Expecting 5-10 chars per string). Would the solr field still carve out memory for the max size? I am having a very hard time finding any documentation regarding how Solr actually manages bytes