# Getting a MaxBytesLengthExceededException for a TextField

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I am getting a `org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash$MaxBytesLengthExceededException`, while trying to insert a list with 9 elements, of which one is 242905 bytes long, into Solr.

ERROR:

```
"error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash$MaxBytesLengthExceededException",
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor$DistributedUpdatesAsyncException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor$DistributedUpdatesAsyncException"],
    "msg":"Async exception during distributed update: Error from server at http://solr-host:8983/solr/search_collection_xx: Bad Request \n\n request: http://solr-host:8983/solr/search_collection_xx \n\n Remote error message: Exception writing document id <document_id> to the index; possible analysis error: Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"text_field_name\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[115, 97, 115, 109, 101, 45, 100, 97, 109, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 108, 121, 99, 107, 97, 47, 37, 50, 50, 37, 50, 48, 109, 101, 116]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 242905. Perhaps the document has an indexed string field (solr.StrField) which is too large",
    "code":400}
}
```

relevant solr_schema:

```
    <dynamicField name="text_field_*"  indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" type="case_insensitive_text" />

    <fieldType name="case_insensitive_text" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

In the [official documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-types-included-with-solr.html) it is stated that StrField has a hard limit of slightly less than 32k, as seen in the error aswell. But here we are using TextField, and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936361/in-solr-what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-text-field) answer it is obvious that 242905 bytes shouldn't be a problem (taking into consideration that the field wasn't multivalued).

So I would like to know what is the problem with inputting these amounts of data and is there a way to avoid the given exception?

Comment: Is your field configured with `DocValues = true`? If so, that would be the problem, set it to `false` and reindex.

Comment: No, the field doesn't have `DocValues = true`. As it is a `TextField` that would be impossible anyway, as they don't support it. [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/docvalues.html#DocValues-EnablingDocValues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this problem, because you're using `KeywordTokenizerFactory`, which is storing all text as it is (without tokenization), which leads in your case to the creation of one huge term, which is impossible to store.

Each term in Solr/Lucene is still limited to 32k, that's why you getting this exception.

Piece of code related to it:

```
        if (len2 > BYTE_BLOCK_SIZE) {
          throw new MaxBytesLengthExceededException("bytes can be at most "
              + (BYTE_BLOCK_SIZE - 2) + " in length; got " + bytes.length);
        }
```

What you should do to avoid limit is to select some tokenizer, which will split your text into multiple terms. One of the most useful ones are: `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`, `StandardTokenizerFactory` and of course Solr/Lucene have much [more](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/tokenizers.html)

Comment: It seems you are correct. Thank you for the answer.